# I am having trouble aligning my header with button

Tags: html, css

I am completely new to CSS and I have a header and a navbar. But when I tried to align the button next to the header it is showing in the navbar line. I tried using the `float` property but it is still in the navigation line. Here's what it looks like.

[image: Navbar with misaligned button]

**HTML**

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

header {
  height: 120px;
  padding: 4px;
}

header h1 {
  font-family: "Amatic Sc";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

.btn {
  width: 10;
  height: 2px;
  padding: 1.375rem 2.625rem 1.375rem 2.625rem;
  border: 0.125rem solid #B49DF1;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  background-color: #B49DF1;
  color: #fff;
  font: 700 0.75rem/0 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #9876F3;
  border: 0.125rem solid #9876F3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <header>
    <h1>Novaturient</h1>
    <---- Next to this should be the button </header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li class="one"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li class="two"><a href="#content">Content</a></li>
          <li class="three"><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
          <li class="four"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li class="fice"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: When running the snippet the result does not look like what you posted as a screenshot, most likely because most of the relevant css does not seem to be included. Could you add that and the "learn more" button to the snippet, so we have a better understanding of how the layouting works?

Answer (score 1):

**Method1:**
We put the `button` inside the `header` and styling it's `position:` to `absolute`. And styling the `header`-> `position: relative;` allowing the `button` to move freely in the header so we style the `button` `bottom: 0;` to make it stick at the bottom of the `header`.

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 4px;
}

header h1 {
  font-family: "Amatic Sc";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

nav ul{
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.btn {
  width: 10;
  height: 2px;
  padding: 1.375rem 2.625rem 1.375rem 2.625rem;
  border: 0.125rem solid #B49DF1;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  background-color: #B49DF1;
  color: #fff;
  font: 700 0.75rem/0 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #9876F3;
  border: 0.125rem solid #9876F3;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Novaturient</h1>
  <!--Here-->
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="one"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="two"><a href="#content">Content</a></li>
        <li class="three"><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
        <li class="four"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li class="fice"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <button class="btn">Learn More</button>
</header>
```

**Method2:**
The `button` is outside the `header`, with the same style `position: absolute;`, but this time we style the `top` to `120px` (**Equeal to `header` height**).

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  height: 120px;
  padding: 4px;
}

header h1 {
  font-family: "Amatic Sc";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000;
}

nav ul{
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav ul li {
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.btn {
  width: 10;
  height: 2px;
  padding: 1.375rem 2.625rem 1.375rem 2.625rem;
  border: 0.125rem solid #B49DF1;
  border-radius: 2rem;
  background-color: #B49DF1;
  color: #fff;
  font: 700 0.75rem/0 'Open Sans', arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #9876F3;
  border: 0.125rem solid #9876F3;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Novaturient</h1>
  <!--Here-->
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li class="one"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li class="two"><a href="#content">Content</a></li>
        <li class="three"><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
        <li class="four"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li class="fice"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<button class="btn">Learn More</button>
```